# Error while registering user via Cognito on local DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, dynamo-local

I faced with such error

```
Request must contain either a valid (registered) AWS access key ID or X.509 certificate.
```

While trying to register an user via Cognito in DynamoDB Local. An user registers ok when I disconnect from DynamoDB and I can create an record in db programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the DynamoDB. Please have a look:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/CommonErrors.html